# java images receiving (web)server

Tags: java, image, http, file, webserver

I want to make a system where java client programs send images to a central server. The central server saves them and runs a website that uses these images.

How should I send the images and how should I receive them? Can I use the same webserver for receiving and displaying the website?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need 3 things:

1. **Upload client** Need to know how to do multipart upload. [See here](http://www.java-tips.org/other-api-tips/httpclient/how-to-use-multipart-post-method-for-uploading.html)
2. **Upload Server** There are a couple of ways. [Apache Commons Upload is my pet](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/).
3. **Displaying File** It's easy. If the files are uploaded somewhere under your web-app directory outside of WEB-INF directory. Just give the path like http://your/apps/base/url/folderName and the listing will come-up for download. 
    There are ways to secure that. But I donot think you need to know that at this stage. By the way [this may help.](http://studyjava.org/ejb/display-or-download-files-using-servlet)

And yes, same server can be used to upload and display (download) the images/files.

Hope this helps.